# Git, different downstream and upstream remote branch

Tags: git

I have two remotes, `origin` with read-only permissions, and my own `private` repository.

I cloned the project from `origin` and will push changes to `private`, but still want pull from the `origin` by default.

How do I define the remote downstream or upstream tracking branch in git?

Comment: You've described a desire to use different remote *repositories*, but the same *branch* (or branch name, to be exact). If you need different branch *names* as well, you will need to modify Sagar Karira's answer, otherwise it's the easy way to do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

`git remote set-url --push private <your-repo-url>`

You can see your pull and push remote branch link by -

`git remote -v`

Please verify if the remote link has been changed.